# How to get all the records in double quotes in csv file using spark dataframe?

Tags: dataframe, csv, pyspark

I am trying to save spark dataframe into csv file but I want all the records in double quotes but it is not generating. Could you help me how to do this?

Example:

```
Source_System|Date|Market_Volume|Volume_Units|Market_Value|Value_Currency|Sales_Channel|Competitor_Name
IMS|20080628|183.0|16470.0|165653.256349|AUD|AUSTRALIA HOSPITAL|PFIZER
```

Desirable Output:

```
Source_System|Date|Market_Volume|Volume_Units|Market_Value|Value_Currency|Sales_Channel|Competitor_Name
"IMS"|"20080628"|"183.0"|"16470.0"|"165653.256349"|"AUD"|"AUSTRALIA HOSPITAL"|"PFIZER"
```

Code I am running:

```
df4.repartition(1).write.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').mode('overwrite').option("quoteAll", 'True').save(Output_Path_ASPAC,quote = '',sep='|',header='True',nullValue=None)
```

Comment: What is your Spark version?

Comment: @ernest_k version 2.4.5

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `df.write.csv` with `quoteAll` set to `True`:

```
df4.repartition(1).write.csv(Output_Path_ASPAC, quote='"', header=True, 
                             quoteAll=True, sep='|', mode='overwrite')
```

Which produces, with your example data:

```
"Source_System"|"Date"|"Market_Volume"|"Volume_Units"|"Market_Value"|"Value_Currency"|"Sales_Channel"|"Competitor_Name"
"IMS"|"20080628"|"183.0"|"16470.0"|"165653.256349"|"AUD"|"AUSTRALIA HOSPITAL"|"PFIZER"
```

Comment: thank you for suggestion. Can we save header without double quotes? only data will save in double quotes.